# RemoveObjectAtIndex doesn't work

Tags: ios, arrays

I want to delete a object from my Array but it doesn't work!

Thats my code:

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:2];
```

It shows me:

> No visible @Interface for "NSArray" declares the selector "removeObjectAtIndex:"

I work in Xcode 6.3.1 with Objective-C.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you use a NSArray instead of NSMutableArray.
The method "removeObjectAtIndex" can only be used with a NSMutableArray.

For example this :

```
NSMutableArray * brokenCars = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                              @"Audi A6", @"BMW Z3",
                              @"Audi Quattro", @"Audi TT", nil];
[brokenCars removeObjectAtIndex:2];
```

Or

```
 NSMutableArray * mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// array is the NSArray that you are using in your code currently
 [mutableArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
 [mutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:2];
```

Take a look at these links to understand better :

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/index.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/

http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsarray

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove objects from `NSArray`, as it is immutable.  For any modification, addition or removal you'll need to use `NSMutableArray`.

So your array object should be of type `NSMutableArray`.

```
 NSMutableArray *array;
```